# Usage of Literal arrays or compounds

Tags: c, arrays, literals

I have a struct

```
typedef struct
{
    int num_bytes;   // number of relevant bytes
    void * bytes_p;  // pointer to bytes
} BYTES_T;
```

which is passed as parameter to a lot of functions on many places.

Usually I use it as follows:

```
uint8_t my_array[] = {0x01, 0x03, 0xff} ; // example array
BYTES_T my_bytes;
my_bytes.bytes_p = my_array;
my_bytes.num_bytes= sizeof(my_array);

...

foo(&my_bytes); // call a function
```

To make parts of my code more readable I would like to avoid simultaneous creation of both the array AND the struct within the same context.

So as a first trial I played around with a macro, using compound literals:

```
#define ARRAYINFO(A) &((BYTES_T ){.bytes_p = ((A)), .num_bytes = sizeof(((A)))})
```

and use it like

```
foo(ARRAYINFO(my_array));
```

This works - when an array is passed. But when I pass the pointer to an array, it will - of course - produce nonsense:

```
uint8_t * array_pointer = my_array; // this is allowed
foo(ARRAYINFO(array_pointer ));     // nonsense for num_bytes because sizeof()
```

Therefore, this is dangerous and not an option.

NextI thought about a construct to create the struct without creating the array explicitly:

```
#define CREATE_BYTES(A) &((BYTES_T ){.bytes_p = ((A)), .num_bytes = sizeof((A))})

BYTES_T my_bytes = CREATE_BYTES(((uint8_t []){1,2,3,4,5}));
```

This seems to work, but I think that the "internal" array , representing the passed literal is created twice in memory (the macro evaluates it twice).

Is there a solution for such idea?

Comment: Honestly, the non-macro version is more readable. I suggest you stick to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This seems to work, but I think that the "internal" array ,
>   representing the passed literal is created twice in memory (the macro
>   evaluates it twice).

From the C99 standard:

> 6.5.3.4/2
>
> The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which
>   may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The size is
>   determined from the type of the operand. The result is an integer. If
>   the type of the operand is a variable length array type, the operand
>   is evaluated; otherwise, **the operand is not evaluated** and the result
>   is an integer constant.

So `A` is evaluated only once in your macro:

```
#define CREATE_BYTES(A) &((BYTES_T ){.bytes_p = ((A)), .num_bytes = sizeof((A))})
```

Comment: It works. But anyway: I think using such macro is too dangerous since A could also be a pointer, in which case we get nonsense for num_bytes.

Comment: I agree, we should avoid these kind of constructions in real world.